# Is there any generic conversion from std::string to numeric type?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, stdstring

There are many ways to convert strings to numbers in C++: `stoi`, `stod`, `stof`, etc. Just like how `std::invoke` is a nice way to call any callable, I am looking for a method that converts `string` value to a generic numeric value.

For instance, instead of something like this:

```
int x = std::stoi("5");
long y = std::stol("5555555555");
```

Something like this:

```
int x = num_convert("55");
long y = num_convert("5555555555");
```

Is there any standard functionality for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking for a `std::hash`?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do this, as a function can only return one type, and you cannot overload functions only changing the return type. I would recommend making different names for the functions, for example `num_convert_long` and `num_convert_int`.

Comment: @cs1349459 Then they might as well be using the functions that are already available in the Standard Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be considered as a generic conversion:

```
#include<sstream>

int main() {
  int x;
  std::stringstream("55") >> x;

  long y;
  std::stringstream("5555555555") >> y;
}
```

A function can return only a single type, thus `long y = num_convert("5555555555")` with a regular function is impossible.

One more hack, help the function to deduce the returned type with the unused parameter:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
T num_convert(const char* s, const T&) {
  return static_cast<T>(std::stoll(s));
}

int main() {
  int x = num_convert("55", x);
  long y = num_convert("5555555555", y);
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643920/calling-function-with-variabl-that-is-being-initialized/73643982#73643982).

Comment: Please show this in the Standard. If you show it, I can easy update the code for using const references.

Comment: You can look at all the dupes linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73643920/calling-function-with-variable-that-is-being-initialized/73643982#73643982). If you think that this is not UB then those dupes won't apply and that question can be reopened. Additionally, this is explained in any beginner c++ book.

Comment: Neither of the dupes refer the C++ Standard. I have only found this UB in C.

Comment: You can confirm that this is UB. See [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zych05m1K23th7P4).

Comment: Ok, changing the answer. But the example warns about another issue "is not usable in a constant expression"

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not (easily) viable in C++. The return value of a function is defined by the function name and the arguments it is given (ie: the result of overload resolution). Your hypothetical `num_convert("55")` and `num_convert("5555555555")` expressions both take the same argument type. Therefore, they must (usually) call the same function which returns the same value.

Thus, the simplest way to achieve what you want would be for such a function to return a proxy object that stores the argument it is given. The proxy would have conversion operators (`operator int`, `operator long`, etc) which would perform the actual conversion.

Of course, this means that `auto i = num_convert("55")` will not actually do the conversion. If the function was given a temporary, `i` would contain a reference to that temporary. Which means that any uses of `i` would be broken, since they would reference a temporary whose lifetime has ended.

The standard doesn't have a function like this.

It would be better to write the type explicitly into the call as a template parameter and then use `auto` deduction instead of using a proxy: `auto i = num_convert<int>("55");`. The standard has no such function either. But really, there's not much difference between `num_convert<int>` and `stoi`, so just use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_(C++_libraries)) then just use

- [`boost::lexical_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) in *Boost.Lexical_Cast 1.0*
- [`boost::cnv::lexical_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/converters_detail.html#boost_convert.converters_detail.lexical_cast_converter) in [*Boost.Convert 2.0*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/convert/doc/html/index.html)

```
auto x = boost::lexical_cast<short>("5"s);
auto y = boost::lexical_cast<long>("5555555555"s);
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Cboost/lexical_cast.hpp%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing+namespace+std::string_literals%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+x+%3D+boost::lexical_cast%3Cshort%3E(%225%22s)%3B%0A++++auto+y+%3D+boost::lexical_cast%3Clong%3E(%225555555555%22s)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+x+%3C%3C+!%27+!%27+%3C%3C+y+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.698671892009585,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27179%27)),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:62.30132810799042,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:62.30132810799042,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

You can also roll out your own lexical_cast like what boost did, if you don't want to use it

For more information read [Boost.LexicalCast](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lexical_cast)